# What is the file size of an Azure Blob (page and block) with snapshots?

Tags: azure, blob, snapshot

I can currently get the file size of each blob in an Azure Blob container and sum them up to get the total.  If the blob is a snapshot I will get a size that is the original base blob size and not necessarily the size of that blob.
This size does not change if the Blob is Premium storage or Standard storage.
Is thee a way to get the actual footprint of the blob snapshot?
Thanks,
Allen

Answer (score 0):

Can not be done as it is looking at the base file.